# Multiple value form tag for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the problem I'm having, and I have tried thinking around, but still can't figure out the solution. So I have two models

1. User
2. Data

and Experience belongs to user, and accepts nested attributes

Now here comes the problem ! I have page/form where I would like to update or insert.

so in the Data model

```
flavor, body
```

So How do I add form tag where I can specify my flavor but let user decide the body so for example, currently I have

```
<%= f.text_field :body, placeholder: "...." %>
```

So how do I do something like (wrong syntax)

```
<%= f.text_field :body, :flavor => "someflav" , placeholder: "...." %>
<%= f.text_field :body, :flavor => "Otherflav" , placeholder: "...." %>
```

and so on...

How does one achieve this ? I have looked around rails api, and but couldn't figure out how to achieve my issue.

Thanks for your consideration and time.

Comment: Just for confirmation, this code doesn't work !

Comment: You can have one `text_field` for `body`  and  `select_tag` for `flavor`. After submitting form you can do your things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fields_for`

Rails constructs input names that help it determine exactly what attribute goes where.

For instance:
`user[datas_attributes][0][body]`

Since (if I am interpreting you correctly) User has many Datas, it would look something like this:

```
<%= fields_for :datas do |data_fields| %>
  <%= data_fields.text_field :body %>
<% end %>
```

There are a few things you need to do to make this work.

In your model, you need to add the following two lines:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :datas
attr_accessible :datas_attributes
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't able to make my question clear. I'm wondering how do, give two attributes.. I only want user to enter body, I want to choose the flavor.

On your given example, I'm struggling to understand, how would I do that ? 

[id="xx" flavour="some" body="abcd"]

Thanks for your response. I appreciate it.

Comment: So is the "flavor" one attribute, and the "body" is another?

Comment: yes. so here is the Data.last output from console.

#<Data id: 631, user_id: 67, flavour: nil, body: "C'mmon dog", created_at: "2013-03-04 18:01:00", updated_at: "2013-03-04 18:01:00">]

I want to decide flavour in code, while user should get to decide body. 

thanks

Comment: OK, so you still want to use `fields_for`, but you can do `<%= data_fields.hidden_field :flavor, :value => "some" %>` to choose the flavor with a hidden field. If you want to do only one at a time, you can do `<%= fields_for @datas.last do .... %>` and so forth.

Comment: Not working.  
Getting  Internal Server Error  
expected Hash (got String) for param `experience'